# Kähler differentials on an Artinian local ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, deformation-theory, local-rings, kahler-differentials

Suppose $R$ is a commutative Artinian local ring over an algebraically closed characteristic 0 field $k$. Suppose $f\in R$ is such that $df=0$ (in the sense that the element $df$ vanishes in the module of Kähler differentials). Is $f$ necessarily in $k$?

Comment: No. Take for $R$ is any finite extension of $k$; then $\Omega _{R/k}=0$.

Comment: Thanks, abx! Forgot to include that.

Comment: Let $k=\mathbb C$ and $R=k[X]/X^2$. It becomes true, if you insist that $R$ is an integral domain.

Comment: @Zero, I don't think thats a counterexample, cause dx doesn't vanish.

Comment: Something like this could work: 1. If $df=0$ in $\Omega_{K/k}$ for a field extension $K$, then $f\in k$, as you have a transcendence basis. 2. Using the exact sequence of $k\to R\to R/M$, where $M$ is the maximal idea, you see that if $df=0$, then $f\in k +M$. Subtracting the $k$-part, you might assume $f\in M$. 3. Replace $R$ by $k+M$, then the differential module is isomorphic to $M/M^2$, by which you conclude that $f\in M^2$. Then your replace $R$ my $k+M^2$ and you iterate this to find $f\in M^k$ for every $k$. For $k$ large, you get $f=0$.

Comment: These examples exist, though I have forgotten the author of the first one. If $f\in k[[x,y]]$ in the maximal ideal, it is a well known theorem that $f^2\in (f_x,f_y)$. An example can be constructed such that $f$ itself is not in this ideal. Further, we can find an $f$ such that $f_x,f_y$ form a regular sequence . Then take $A=k[[x,y]]/(f_x,f_y)$. So, $f\neq 0\in A$, but $df=0$.

Comment: @Mohan: Do you have a reference for the "well known theorem"? That doesn't seems obvious to me.

Comment: @abx    It is called Briancon-Skoda theorem and it is more general. For $n$ variable power series $f^n$ belongs to the ideal of partial derivatives .

Comment: @Mohan: Thank you! By the way, I don't see why you need this. It seems to me that any $f\notin(f'_x,f'_y)$ will do the job.

Comment: @abx No, it is not necessary , just mentioned it .

Comment: @Mohan Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. If you wanna post as an answer I'd gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally remembered the example (though not the reference). Take $f=x^2y^2+x^5+y^5\in R=\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$. Then $f_x,f_y$ form a regular sequence in $R$ and thus $R/I$ where $I=(f_x,f_y)$ is an Artin local ring. One checks $f\not\in I$. Thus, $df=0\in\Omega^1_{R/I}$, but $f\neq 0$ in $R/I$.